# Freestyle Line Separated By Material

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine, freestyle

I am trying to have my freestyle line be separated by each individual material, so it goes around each material separately here is an image[image]

as you can see i am trying to mimic the portal stye of animation, does anyone know the best way of achieving this? just to clarify the white line should surround the whole black material and there should be no lines inside like there is in the picture

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you’re looking for, but in the View Layer properties under “Freestyle Line Set”, there’s a bunch of checkboxes that determine how freestyle lines are generated. One of them is “Material Boundary”, try checking that. (This assumes you’re using the properties editor mode (default), and not scripting)

Comment: that didn't work but contour did so thanks haha